# How to set the build path format?

Tags: buildpath

At present the working folders for our builds on TFS 2017 use the following format:-

{Agent.HomeDirectory}_work{BuildDefinitionId}

So our builds are put in folders like this:-

D:\buildagent_work\42

Is there any way in which I can change the format to include the build number like this?

{Agent.HomeDirectory}_work{BuildDefinitionId}{BuildNumber}

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to change the build directory folder's name (default is .....\1).Unfortunately, there isn't any way to change it.

Besides,windows has 260 character file path length limitation which easy to happen during the build. Under normal circumstances, you'd better to keep the path as short as possible.

---

**Update 05/24**

You could use [Copy Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) and [Publish Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts) task to a file share instead of server store the build artifacts for troubleshooting. You could directly copy `Agent.BuildDirectory`, the local path on the agent where all folders for a given build definition are created. For example: `c:\agent\_work\1`

The tasks will copy the build agent folder to a staging folder and then publish them.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Patrick. Yes, I agree that it is essential to keep the path as short as possible. However, a build number would increase the length of the path by 4 or 5 characters ("...\123" or "...\1234"). If TFS didn't have a hard-wired path ("buildagent") then I could recover these characters by changing the path (e.g. "ba").

Comment: @BillStokes Why you need to change the build directory folder's name to this? As you said, the number stands for the build definition. If it's related to buildnumber, every time a new build triggered there will generated a new folder and multiple subfolders such as `c:\agent\_work\1234\a ` and `c:\agent\_work\1234\s` and so on. There maybe a lot of folders under the _work directory. Moreover, the files under \a \s is related to the latest build\buildnumber. If you just want to keep the source of older buildnumber, you could use copy task in build definition to achieve this.

Comment: We need to keep previous build artifacts to allow for diagnosis of build problems. Often by the time the investigation starts the most recent build is not the build where the problem occured. Sometimes this is not relevant but sometimes it is. The behaviour that we are looking for is essentially the same behaviour as for TFS 2013 - it seems like a step backwards for TFS 2017.

Comment: @BillStokes In this situation, you could use [Copy and Publish Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts) task to a file share instead of server. The task will copy build artifacts to a staging folder and then publish them. If you are using TFS2017 suggest you use Copy Files and Publish Build Artifacts tasks separately.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite the same thing. Often it isn't the build artifacts that I am interested in. It is the detritous left behind during the build process. When I am diagnosing a build issue I might need to see what the build folder looked like during the build.

Comment: @BillStokes If so, you could directly copy `Agent.BuildDirectory`, **the local path on the agent where all folders for a given build definition are created**. For example: `c:\agent\_work\1` . It's what you are looking for. More build variables please refer: [Build variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#predefined-variables)

Comment: Yes, that would work. The only downside now is that the build retention does not apply to this copied folder so I would need to manage its lifetime manually.